# Survey bug: Asked a question that does not apply to me

Tags: bug, survey

In the survey, I responded that I am not employed; I am a student. Then, I was asked if "that salary was weekly, monthly, or yearly." [image]

Obviously, as a high school student, I don't earn a salary. How should I answer this?

Comment: I don't even understand that question. That question was the first question I was asked on the salary topic. Is the question about how often I receive my salary?

Comment: Better yet: ask for a raise!

Comment: Well, how often do you get paid nothing?

Comment: you can be a university student + employeed.. that is why they ask that question even though you chose student before..

Comment: @PeterHaddad hmmm hein ? I might be wrong, but i though Salary section was made to calculate salaries as if you where working in a computer related area. If you work in a restaurant... i mean... don't write your salary. Actually, how is it supposed to work ?

Comment: I meant a student and employed in a computer company obviously..

Comment: ho right, that makes sens

Comment: Isn't that question just in addition to a textbook where you enter the salary? I thought it's  meant to specify if you entered monthly or yearly salary. When you earn nothing enter 0 and the radiobuttons don't matter.

Comment: I never entered any number.

Comment: Strange. I think I got this on a two question page where first one asked about my gross salary and second part were the radiobuttons.

Comment: I was not asked this question, but I _did_ put in my salary...

Comment: One thing that should be remembered is that once you get to post secondary education (At least in the United States) it is possible to earn enough scholarships/grants that you end up getting money back from them and end up getting paid to go to school.

Answer (score 6):

**1. First option (best option ?)**

The "I don't get paid" option is obviously missing.

EDIT : Thanks to people comments

Many people get paid every 2 weeks, an also missing option.

Finally, some get paid every 2 days.

**2. Alternative**

There could be a last option saying : If the three options above does not represent how you get paid, type in the frequency.

And that is where a NOT working person would type "never"

If there are too many different frequencies someone can get paid, this might be the best solution.

Comment: What about fortnight (two weeks) which is common in Australia.

Comment: @ACatInLove perhaps fortnightly then? can you do that with fortnight?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Salaried are monthly and wage staff are fortnightly. Rent is usually fortnightly as well but mortgages are monthly.

Comment: [off] I just played Undertale, so I cannot trust you. =|

Comment: @ACatInLove in fact, the 2 weeks option is also missing, i'm adding it to answer

Comment: @carla I should have take Sans instead...

Comment: I get paid bi-daily.

Comment: @TinyGiant Every 2 days ? Really ?

Comment: Every 2 days. Really.